# Display custom text if there is no comments

Tags: comments, theming

I want to display custom text on a node if there is no comments yet.
I think i should check for comments count in preprocess_node, and somehow add the text below Comments title.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook) {
  if($variables['comment_count'] === '0') {
     //somehow i need to display text - There is not comments yet
  }
}
```

How can achieve this? here is an example of how it should looks like:

[image: description]

**EDIT:**
Also i have found better solution, may be useful for someone.
(using Zen theme - aka STARTERKIT modified)
I have added `comments-wrapper.tpl.php`

And in a `template.php` added preprocess function of this wrapper

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_comments_wrapper(&$variables) {
    $variables['MYTHEME_comment_title'] = t('Comments');
      $commented_node = $variables['node'];

      if(!empty($commented_node) && is_object($commented_node)){
        $comment_count = 0;
        if(isset($commented_node->comment_count)){
          $comment_count = $commented_node->comment_count;
        }
        $variables['MYTHEME_comment_title'] = format_plural($comment_count, '1 comment', '@count comments');
         if($comment_count == 0) {
            $variables['MYTHEME_comment_title'] = t('Comments');
            $variables['empty_comments'] = t('There is no comments yet');
     }
}
```

And in a `comments-wrapper.tpl.php` i have printed out `$empty_comments` variable

```
  <?php print $empty_comments; ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your node.tpl.php you could check the $comment_count variable to see if there are comments. If so, render the comments, if not display your alternet text.

Example:

```
<?php if ($comment_count > 0 ): ?>
  <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
<?php else: ?>
        <strong> 0 comments yet</strong>
        <?php echo l('Be the first','commentpath'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```